# Fix result mapping when using pagination in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I want to implement pagination with mongodb in my spring application.

I found solutions on the internet, but they all allow to make 2 queries, the first to retrieve the list of data, and the second query to calculate the number of documents, which is a bit expensive.

I implemented my own function

```
protected inline fun <reified Result> getPagedResult(
    aggregation : Aggregation,
    inputClass : KClass<*>,
    page : Long,
    limit : Long,
    direction : Direction,
    vararg orderBy : String
) : PagedList<Result>
{
    val skip : Long = if (page == 0L)
    {
        0
    }
    else
    {
        page * limit 
    }
    
    val finalAggregation : Aggregation = Aggregation.newUpdate(
        *aggregation.pipeline.operations.toTypedArray(),
        Aggregation.sort(direction, *orderedFields),
        Aggregation.facet().and(
            Aggregation.count().`as`("totalItems"),
            Aggregation.addFields()
                    .addFieldWithValue("currentPage", page)
                    .addFieldWithValue("limit", limit)
                    .build()
        ).`as`("info").and(
            Aggregation.skip(skip),
            Aggregation.limit(limit)
        ).`as`("data"),
        Aggregation.unwind("\$info")
    )
    
    val docPagedList: DocPagedList = mongodb.aggregate(
        finalAggregation,
        inputClass.java,
        DocPagedList::class.java
    ).uniqueMappedResult ?: DocPagedList()
    
    val result = PagedList<Result>()
    result.info = docPagedList.info
    result.data = docPagedList.data.filterNotNull().mapNotNull {
        mongodb.converter.mapValueToTargetType(it, Result::class.java, dbRefResolver)
    }
    
    return result
}
```

it's a general function that can be used from multiple places to return multiple data types, that's why the result type is generic.

the problem here is that the result returned by mongo is of type document, so the ids are of type ObjectId. so if i directly put the desired result type, i will get a conversion exception, because the mongo converter doesn't know how to convert objectId to string.

that's why I chose to convert the result to a pagination of documents and then tried to map the list of documents to my desired type, but i got this exception:

```
ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.Document] to type [my type]
```

besides the ObjectId I want to map to string (because that's the type of the ids in my objects), I have other types that I need to map them too.
that's why I don't want to treat the ObjectId individually, and I want the converter to do it as it does in normal scenarios, when I return directly a list of data.

how can i adapt my solution to fix this problem?

this is my generic result class

```
open class PagedList<Type>
{
    var data : List<Type> = emptyList()
    
    var info : PagingInfo = PagingInfo()
}
```

and this is my DocPagedList

```
class RawPagedList : PagedList<Document>()
```

Comment: Skip and limit work well for the first few pages, but as you go deeper it becomes more and more expensive.  A better approach is to keep track of the ranges already selected and apply a filter that excludes already fetched documents from the next page data.  If the data is sorted by the same filter predicate field, no skip is required.  A limit may still be beneficial.  This comment does not help with your current conversion problem, however.

Comment: thank you @barrypicker for your comment, I will take your advise into consideration to improve my query